# How can I combine two different dylib into a simple one for my Mac application?

Tags: xcframework

I am trying to build ffmpeg for Intel and M1 platform for my application.

I got some problem, because when I put arm64 dylibs I got error that no x86_64 dylibs available. And I got arm64 dylibs not available when I put x86_64 dylibs.

Can I combine these two set of dylibs into a single one then I don't need to change the dylibs on different platform?

XCFramework or ??

Thank you.

Eric

Answer (score 2):

You can create so called "fat" library. It is dylib which combine several architectures for one platform (MacOS in your case).

```
lipo -create libx86_64.dylib libarm64.dylib -output libcombined.dylib
```

Resulted dylib you can include in your project and it will compile fine for both archs.

If you want it more comfortable you can build framework from combined library and header folder

```
xcodebuild -create-xcframework -library libcombined.dylib -headers path/to/headers/directory -output output.xcframework
```

In this case you'll need to include only framework in your project

Comment: When adding `.dylib`s to xcframeworks I run into `[!] Invalid XCFramework slice type .dylib` when adding these frameworks as `vendored_frameworks` in a podspec.

https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/lib/cocoapods/xcode/xcframework/xcframework_slice.rb#L63-L77

Comment: And when using `vendored_libraries` instead,

`s.vendored_libraries = 'Frameworks/mylib_dylib.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/libmylib_dylib.dylib', 'Frameworks/mylib_dylib.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/libmylib_dylib.dylib'`

then the iOS Simulator vs iOS device slicing isn't happening `[!] The 'Pods-Runner' target has libraries with conflicting names: libmylib_dylib.dylib`

Comment: @DacoHarkes You must separate dylibs for different platforms (macOS, iOS, iOS Simulator) when you add them into XCFramework. There may be the next combined dylibs: ios-arm64_arm64e, ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator, macos-arm64_x86_64. Each dylib is added as separate option: `xcodebuild -create-xcframework -library libios.dylib -headers path/to_headers_ios/ -library libios_simulator.dylib -headers path/to_headers_ios_simulator/ -library libmacos.dylib -headers path/to_headers_macos/ -output output.xcframework`